# Unable to clone a bitbucket repository which does not have .git at end

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket repository path similar to this: https://abc123@bitbucket.org/abc123/SomeFolder/

It does not have `.git` at the end.

I am trying to clone this repo by following the steps:

```
$ cd LocalFolder
$ git init
$ git clone https://abc123@bitbucket.org/abc123/SomeFolder/
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Cloning into 'SomeFolder'...
fatal: repository 'remote path' not found
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to clone only one sub-directory? You can't clone only a subdirectory like in CVS or svn, you have to clone the entire repo. Also make sure it's actually git and not mercurial and that the path is correct in the first place (not something we can check since you provided a fake path). you also don't need the `git init` btw, you can just use `git clone ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only clone the whole repository, not a folder.
Try copy pasting the whole url